# Before storage why should a Lithium Polymer battery be charged up to only 40-60%

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lipo

While storing a Lithium Polymer battery cell or a device with a Lithium Polymer battery why should we make sure to discharge the battery to 40-60% (and only then put it to storage)?

What happens if you store a Lithium Polymer battery with 100% charge and WHY DOES IT HAPPEN?

I am more interested in "WHY DOES IT HAPPEN" part and if someone can explain to me in terms of Chemistry and Electrical Engineering involved I will be very glad.

Answer (score 7):

Actually this recommendation is more for LiIon batteries - LiPo batteries don't seem so much affected by it. The reason I see [most times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery#Prolonging_battery_pack_life) is the self discharge in combination with the protection circuits. The protection circuitry disables the battery when it has been discharged too deep - recovering it from this state is non-ideal for the battery as well as requires a charger capable of trickle-charge preconditioning. To avoid this, the battery should be left in a state that is charged enough.

Also, a constant high charge level [shortens the battery life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery#Disadvantages). So its best to charge the battery to an intermediate level only.

Since LiPo batteries don't discharge as much, they are not so much affected by this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if a Lithium battery is stored fully charged at 25 degrees celcius for one year, it will lose approximately 20% of its capacity.  Apparently if they are stored at a 40% state of charge, or at a much lower temperature, the loss of capacity is negligible.  Thus the recommendation for the state of charge storage.  I don't know if the liFe have the same problem. 
Sorry, I do not know why it happens.